# Execute cleanup tasks after page reloading is confirmed

Tags: javascript, browser

As we know,

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
      return "are you sure?";
}
```

shows a native confirmation dialog.

[image]

If we press the **"Reload this Page"** button, page will be refreshed or be redirected else where. Suppose, we have some cleanup tasks to be performed when user hits the **"Reload this Page"** button. But as the code indicates, the confirmation dialog is appeared due to the `return` statement. We cannot actually execute any code after the `return` statement of a function. So how can we actually perform some more tasks even after we `return` ? Doing cleanup tasks before confirmation doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `window.onunload`?

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
    return "are you sure?";
}

window.onunload=function(){
    console.log("doing something");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8b9wyjas/

Comment: Thanks. I was totally unaware about this !